# My husband married me temporarily but I did not know it was only temporarily,what should I do?

Tags: nikah, talaq, husband-wife, nikah-al-mutah

Assalamu alaikum.

Before I got married I thought me and my husband were going to get married to be together until death.

I just found out that my husband always had the intention of being married to me temporarily. I'm very hurt and feel betrayed. He only wanted us to be married temporary but I never knew that.

I am his second wife but I thought it was to be together forever. Now I feel like I'm just an option to him. We have only been married for 4 months. Many of the things he said have not come true.

He didn't say promise but for me they were promises. I honestly feel like an object to him. He constantly tells me to find a new husband and tells me hurtful words.

When I tell him of the things that hurt me he says to find someone new. Sometimes I feel like he is trying to get rid of me. I'm very hurt.

My heart is broken because when we married I thought we were both in love with each other and wanted to be with each other but now I don't think that's the case. He says things that will hurt me on purpose. I asked him if he means them and he said yes he means it. He doesn't care if he hurts my feelings and he thinks I'm always wrong. I don't know what to do.

Sometimes I feel like I hate him. Sometimes I feel like telling him I'm done. I've tried to defend myself but he tells me to stop acting tough that I'm not going to do anything because I love him.  He doesn't have respect for me.

I'm starting to feel like I'm done. But I know divorce isn't liked in Islam. I need advise. We do not have a marriage contract.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam StackExchange the Q&A site about Islam. Please not unlike the typical Internet forum advise requests are hardly on topic here, as they might lead to opinion based answers or would be regarded as too broad (which are close reasons on SE). I strongly recommend you to learn more about this site by taking our [tour], checking our [help] and to edit your Question -using the edit "Button" below your original post- to make it clearly answerable.

Comment: Your question sounds like an advice-request, which is full of details that don't really help to even give the hint of an advice: You neither said whether you've got a marriage contract? Where you live? Nor what's your or your husbands sect? etc. ... if your husband only intended to marry you temporarily he might be a sinner from sunni perspective, for shi'a such marriages are allowed however it's unclear to me whether a case like this would be accepted.

Comment: What @G.Bach quotes is in the whole corcert and solves the technical part of your Issue. Of course it can't take away your hurt or any feeling about your situation! Talaq might be considered as bad, but it is perfectly halal, but we don't erally know your circumstances and cultural "background" to give you a "correct" advise. Note that I've lately read in an article that some scholar of the 4th or 5th century said that at his time about no men and no women have never got divorced after marriage it was perfectly fine and usual to marry a women who has been divorced by more than one husband!

Comment: @Medi1Saif Do you remember the article? If it's in English, I'd be interested in that.

Comment: @G.Bach honestly no but it is possible that I've read it on wikipedia (AR), if I should have bookmarked it I could tell you...!

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of domestic violence. If what you are saying is true, you most certainly should consider divorcing that evil man. Divorce is discouraged but divorce is necessary if the spouse doesn't act justly kindly towards the other.